# Live Heatmap generation in OpenCV python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, opencv3.0

I want to generate heatmap while the video is playing basically i want to show the crowd density. I have no idea how to do this i am doing this now it calculates the heatmap after processing the whole video i just want to make it live , like video is playing and color is spreading over different places.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


class Motion:
 def __init__(self):
    print("Motion Detection Object Created")
    # input file name of video
    self.inname = 'data.mp4'

    # file name to save
    self.outname = "C:/Heatmap"


 def prep(self):

    # just read the first frame to get height and width
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.inname)

    ret, self.orig_image = cap.read()
    width = np.size(self.orig_image, 1)
    height = np.size(self.orig_image, 0)
    frame_size = (height, width)

    # make accumulator image of the same size
    self.accumulator = np.zeros((height, width), np.float32)  # 32 bit accumulator

 def run(self):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.inname)
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=1000, detectShadows=True)
    #print(fgbg[0])

    while (1):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #print(frame)

        if not ret:
            break
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        self.accumulator = self.accumulator + fgmask

def write(self):

    self.ab = cv2.convertScaleAbs(255 - np.array(self.accumulator, 'uint8'))

    # only get reasonable high values, above mean
    ret, self.acc_thresh = cv2.threshold(self.ab, self.ab.mean(), 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)

    # make a color map
    acc_col = cv2.applyColorMap(self.acc_thresh, cv2.COLORMAP_RAINBOW)

    cv2.imwrite(str(self.outname + "/heatmap.jpg"), acc_col)

    # add to original frame
    backg = cv2.addWeighted(np.array(acc_col, "uint8"), 0.45, self.orig_image, 0.55, 0)

    cv2.imwrite(str(self.outname + "/heatmap_background.jpg"), backg)


   # MAIN ENTRY POINT


  if __name__ == "__main__":
    motionVid = Motion()
    motionVid.prep()
    motionVid.run()
    motionVid.write()
```

Comment: it looks like the way you have it now only saves one image at the end that is the most recent value of the accumulator.  But also, your accumulator sums during the whole video...what does that achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In your `write` function, try adding this :

```
VideoWriter video("output.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),10,Size(frame_width,frame_height));
```

here `frame_width` = width & `frame_height` = height

You can get a list of codecs for video compressions on the OpenCV documentation.